# How to increase heap memory - node.js

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I recently tried to download angular/cli using npm but angular/cli requires a higher version of npm to download angular/cli. I used the following command:

```
npm install -g npm
```

but it returned an error that says

```
JAVASCRIPT heap out of memory
```

I tried to do this command in many different ways:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8000
mode —max_old_space_size=8000
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I think that you don't have enough free memory even for updating NPM. What is your current free RAM?

Comment: @Jehy My computer has 16 GB RAM

Comment: What about free memory? May be you have none available?

Comment: @Jehy I fixed the problem I just add the path of npm to the  Path variable. But when I type ‘ng’ in the command it doesn’t work.